# Routing with angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

My server using angular for routing. My server sending to the browser a HTML file that contains js file with routing (using angular js).

my server code (send to browser check.html contains the routing file main.js) :

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express(); // express.createServer();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get("/*", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/check.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

check.html code:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

after the browser gets the check.html file he doesnt redirect it to main.js in order to use the routing. I tried to debug it but the browser is stuck without doing nothing. my app is local and the url im trying to connect to is:

http://localhost:8080/stations

and all the files are loaded correctly without any errors on the console.

main.js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'menu.html'
            })
        .when('/stations',
            {
                controller: 'StationsController',
                templateUrl: 'check2.html'
            })
        .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'menu.html'
            })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

myApp.controller('StationsController', function($scope){
    $scope.check = {name:"ELAD!!"};
});
```

check2.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>{{check.name}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the console tells you ? and check that your .js files contains really html content, and not the content of check.html

Comment: @GalSosin That's a frequent misconception to mix the server and client side when new to angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok let's start fresh on angular..

## Angular 101

You may know angular is essential for **Single Page Application** so what happens is you supply the first page that is `check.html` in your case but you should name it `index.html` it's a convention. khair.. what happens is when a `route` transition occurs in the your angular code that is something after `#` an it's purely client end or a soft redirection. so angular fires an AJAX request to retrieve the resource matching your `templateUrl` from router. then plugs it inside the `<div ng-view></div>` thus the redirection. notice the `ng-view`.

## Well bellow is the proposed solution

the link should be http://localhost:8080/#stations as the angular matches handles the routes after `#`. Other routes like the link you provided are handed to the `server`.

your `check.html` should look like this.

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and your `check2.html` should be in your  public directory and have the code like

```
<div>
   <p>{{check.name}}</p>
</div>
```